# Vue JS throwing type error for delete request using a new Form

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Using a form for a delete request in VUE js. It is throwing a type error that delete is not a function.

```
deleteProject({ commit }, projectid) {
        let project = new Form();
        return project
            .delete(__baseUrl + 'myg_project/' + projectid)
            .then(function(response) {
                console.log('Prodect deleted ' + projectid);
                commit('updateResp', response.msg);
            });
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `Form` your own defined custom class with a delete method, in that case, it should work just make sure it's not private & it returns a promise?

If you want to submit a form data using what I can assume is a `vuex action`, then you probably want to do something like:

```js
deleteProject({ commit }, projectid) {
    fetch(__baseUrl + 'myg_project/' + projectid, {
        method: 'DELETE'
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
      console.log('Prodect deleted ' + projectid);
      commit('updateResp', response.msg);
    })
},
```

Here I'm using fetch API to send DELETE request to the backend.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me to understand the issue. Yes, Form is a custom class and has a different method name for delete requests. I could not figure it out, thanks for helping.